# Execution failed for task ':expo-image-picker:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':expo-image-picker:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to version 10.0.0 and it worked
Also tried to upgrade to the latest but the app just gave me a blank screen

So try to change the version to `~10.0.0` in `package.json` or `yarn add expo-image-picker --latest`